# Which subclasses of the STream class support seeking in C# (not in the docs ffs)

Tags: c#, stream, seek

Generally, I just want to know which streams in C# support seeking. I checked the docs and the Microsoft geniuses explained the concept, but didn't actually say which ones can be seeked.

Comment: There is the [`CanSeek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.canseek?view=netframework-4.8) property.

Comment: So are you asking for a list or for a way to find out? Every `Stream` derived class implements the [`CanSeek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.canseek?view=netframework-4.8) property that tells you if it can seek.

Comment: _The microsoft geniuses_ did a good job and you can tell that it's not something you can generalize in "this class can and this one can't". It states: "Seek capability depends on the kind of backing store a stream has." Maybe they should've added "and that might be different for every stream so you have to examine the CanSeek property before seeking" but imo they explained it good enough. Also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57810116/10883465) below for the full text with links etc.

Comment: There are no streams in c#, there are streams in the .NET libraries and probably a lot more from other vendors. Apart from `MemoryStream` and `FileStream` I actually can't think of any other (.net)-stream capable of seeking (but I might be forgetting something).

Comment: The goal was to not have to test it out myself and thus ask here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream):

> Streams can support seeking. Seeking refers to querying and modifying the current position within a stream. Seek capability depends on the kind of backing store a stream has. For example, network streams have no unified concept of a current position, and therefore typically do not support seeking.

You cannot just list all those who can seek, it depends on what backing store is behind the stream.

If you want to know if a stream can seek, examine the [`CanSeek`-Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.canseek). If it's true, you can use the seeking properties and methods available. Again, see [the docs (remarks section)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.canseek#remarks).

> If a class derived from Stream does not support seeking, calls to Length, SetLength, Position, and Seek throw a NotSupportedException.

Comment: The goal was to not have to test it out myself and thus ask here

Comment: so as long as I am using a system that has consistent bit streams throughout, then I should be good?

Comment: The thing is, it could change and it's not always possible to say 'it's always true for StreamX'. As far as I'm concerned it shouldn't change once you're using it though. Just don't _assume_ it can seek unless you either test it or it states somewhere that this stream will _always_ support seeking.